# BAAN - MS SQL table query - Bill Of Material explosion

Tags: sql, sql-server, legacy, erp, baan

Hello we are archiving our legacy BAAN IV system in an Archiving Agnostic Platform.
I need to produce a BillOfMaterial explosion MS SQL query using standard BAAN Table.
Giving as input main Material my goal is to obtain all Sub-Material with associated quantity and Cost.
I'm not BAAN expert but I guess I should use  tiitm001(item master) + tibom010(BOM) +  ticst(Cost) + tirou(Routing) tables.

Example:
from given Master Item "123-456" reiterate the query until a Sub Item (child node) won't have a SubItem Populated:

[image]

I need to produce an extract.

Just wondering if there's some MS SQL query example or some comments as this topic may be already been treated.

Thanks a lot

Comment: you're going to need to provide more information here.

Comment: You may want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Comment: Hello Tanner, sorry to have such a poor information: I don't know the BAAN data model, but I know in principle what I need. I've added an explicative (I guess) screenshot

Comment: Sample data in a *tabular format* along with desired results would help.  Your data does not look like a database table so it is a bit hard to follow the logic.

Comment: Hello Gordon, I'm looking for somebody that is already well known of BaaN data model (I'm unable to tag this question specific for Baan). I don't know field and aggregation between tables that could affect properly the result. I could just represent what interaction I'm supposed to have to generate the output.